# homologies of some subsets of ${R}^{n}$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

This might be something well-known.

For $1\le k\le n$, let $A(n,k)\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be the set  of points $x=(x_{1},...,x_{n}%
)$ with at least $k$ distinct coordinates. Then what are the homologies of
$A(n,k)$?

For example, $A(n,2)$ is equal to $\mathbb{R}^{n}\backslash\Delta$,
where $\Delta$ is the diagonal, thus it is homotopy equivalent to
$\mathbb{S}^{n-2}$.

Comment: @YCor: Thanks for the comment. I realized that I was thinking of tuples, but asking about finite sets. I will edit the question.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, indeed. Maybe it's better to ask a new question

Comment: $A(n,1)=\mathbf{R}^n$. $A(n,n)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^n\times\{1,\dots,n!\}$. As you say, $A(n,2)$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^2\times\mathbf{S}^{n-2}$.

Comment: $A(n,3)$ is homeomorphic to the product of $\mathbf{R}$ with ($\mathbf{R}^{n-1}$ minus $2^{n-1}-1$ lines through zero), which itself is homeomorphic to the product of $\mathbf{R}^2$ with ($\mathbf{S}^{n-2}$ minus $2^{n}-2$ points); $\mathbf{S}^{n-2}$ minus $2^{n}-2$ points is homeomorphic to $\mathbf{R}^{n-2}$ minus $2^{n}-3$ points for $n\ge 2$. The homology is not hard to compute: for $n\ge 3$ it's the homology of a bunch of $2^n-3$ $(n-3)$-spheres.

Comment: I guess $A(n,n-1)$ deformation retracts onto a graph but I don't have a proof now.

Comment: A related paper (from a deleted answer) is *The homology of "k-equal'' manifolds and related partition lattices. 
Adv. Math. 110 (1995), no. 2, 277–313.* sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870885710122 It computes the homology of $M_{n,k}\subset\mathbf{R}^n$, defined by the condition that no $k$-uple of coordinates is constant, so it's a bit distinct, but of the same flavor.

Answer (score 3):

Let me try again after deleting an answer based on a misunderstanding of the question. (Thanks to @YCor for pointing this out.)

Edited thanks to observations of Dan Petersen.

Your space $A(n,k)$ is obtained from ${\mathbb R}^n$ by deleting a bunch of subspaces.  Thus the theorem of Goresky and McPherson dealing with complements of unions of subspaces applies.  This says that

$$\widetilde{H}^d(A(n,k)) \cong \bigoplus_X \widetilde{H}_{codim(X)-2-d}(\Delta(0,X)).$$

Here $X$ runs through the set of intersections of collections deleted subspaces, which is partially ordered by reverse inclusion, $\Delta(0,X)$ is the order complex of the interval $(0,X)$ ($0$ is the ambient space ${\mathbb R}^n$, which is not included in the sum), and $codim(X)$ is the usual codimension of the subspace $X$ in ${\mathbb R}^n$.

The intersection poset for this union of subspaces is isomorphic with the poset of set partitions of $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ having less than $k$ parts, ordered by reverse inclusion.  As this is a rank selected subposet of the lattice of all set partitions, it is a Cohen-Macaulay poset. This means that the homology of $\Delta(0,X)$ is concentrated in degree $rank(X)-2$.  On the other hand, if $X$ has $j$ parts, then $X$ has rank $k-j$ (in the intersection post) and codimension $n-j$.

It follows now from direct computation that the reduced homology of your space is concentrated in degree $n-k$.  As Dan Petersen pointed out to me, if $k \leq n-2$, then $A(n,k)$ is simply connected, and it follows from the Hurewicz Theorem that $A(n,k)$ is homotopy equivalent to a wedge of spheres of dimension $n-k$.

Calculating the number of such spheres involves determining the M\"obius function on the intersection poset, which might or might not be tough.